# Using external library function is giving error

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have created the single View application .In that single view application

1- I placed the text view on storyboard and linked that text view  to View controller IBOutlet

2- Then i copied the library files(BWUtilities.h and BWUtilities.m) in to project and included BWUtilities.h in ViewController.h .

3- Then i created simple function runTest that is called from ViewDid Load .runTest function is using library function

void message ( NSString *format, ... );

```
- (void)runTest {
    message(@"Testbed version %@", kTestbedVersion);
    for ( id o in @[@"Klaatu", @"barada", @"nikto"]) {
        message(@"object is %@", o);
    }
}
```

On running this program it is giving error on message function

void message ( NSString *format, ... );
[image]
How i can remove these error and and get the required output .From this link you can download the sample project from correction :https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5pNDpbvZ8SnTEZ4cjZydEtfaDA/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need add your `BWUtilities.m` in your project Build Phases->Compile Sources section as is show in the images

[image]
[image]

After that you will start receiving some errors that you will resolve replacing

```
#import "BWutilities.h"
```

by this in your BWUtilities.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BWUtilities.h"
```

Finally remove your `#import "BWUtilities.h"` from your ViewController.h and must work

## to remove the warning

You need pass the UITextView declaration from `BWUtilities.h` to `BWUtilities.m`

```
// populated from loadDidView
UITextView * messageTextView;
```

and after that you need to import `BWUtilities.h` in your `ViewController.m`

```
#import "BWutilities.h"
```

Here is your code https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-nd1aJDZQUccmF6MzdYM19ZYzg

Hope this helps

Comment: I have implemented thing you have mentioned above.                " Semantic Issue Group:  implicit declaration of function 'message' is invalid in C99  "   error in "runTest "  function online this line--> {   message(@"Testbed version %@", kTestbedVersion);   }

Comment: @frincit can i post your code in github for you?, for me work just fine

Comment: sample code with error is on this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5pNDpbvZ8SnUzhIWFFrQWd4R00/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @frincit is a warning, but the app runs and show what you need, this warning I don't know how fix it

Comment: this Line :      message(@"Testbed version %@", kTestbedVersion);    is giving Error:   "Implicit declaration of function 'message' is invalid in C99" Build failed .Program stops it execution ..

Comment: I have made above mentioned changes .in spite of that Build failed .Program fail to execute.I dont know the cause of this error " Apple Mach-O Linker Error Group Showing Recent Issues clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) "--- 
sample code with error is on this link is:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5pNDpbvZ8SnVHY3WVVqVm9FN1k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @frincit fixed removing your BWUtilities from the project and adding it again, i will post your code in google drive for you, check my updated answer